# In Excel, how to fill blank cells with the last preceding non-blank cell?

Tags: excel

How to fill blank cells with the last preceding non-blank cell ?

For example, I have this two-columns sheet:

```
A   
    abc
    dce
    fds
B   
    kjh
    abc
```

What I would like is:

```
A   
A   abc
A   dce
A   fds
B   
B   kjh
B   abc
```

I tried a formula like "=IF(ISBLANK(A2), A1, A2)" but it warns me about redundancy and doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In a  *"manual"* fashion, you could do the following:

Select the column, go to Edit > Go To > Special > Blanks, type = in the formula bars, hit the up arrow then Ctrl+Enter. you should now have the cells fill with the values above

- In a more *"automated"* fashion using VBA, you could do the following:

Select the range where you want to fill the blank cells,

[image]

Then click on *Developer* Tab -> Visual Basic -> Insert -> Module

Then paste the code in the Module, and click on *run*:

[image]

Code:

```
 Sub Fill_Blank_Cells()
 Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
 Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
 End Sub
```

As @Jerry rightfully pointed out, make sure to copy-paste special the values in order to remove the formulas behind your filled column. This will prevent any undesirable results later!

Comment: Thank you Mariam, but there seems to be a problem with the code, no matter how many cells I select, it only fills the first blank cell!

Comment: Try the "manual" method too (see my edited answer above). In the meantime, I will check the code one more time.

Comment: @user2445 The code works perfectly for me.. Make sure to select the entire column, then hit run in the Module.

Comment: @user2445 I posted a detailed description of how to execute the code! Try that again if you wish :)

Comment: @Mariam You can add the paste values in yours, go ahead :)

Comment: @Jerry I made sure to reference you in the post :D

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this in Excel 2016, and selected the entire column, but after clicking RUN, it returns "Run-time error '1004: No cells were found."

When I then click on the DEBUG button it selects the 2nd row
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select

This formula is what I used for

If column D IS BLANK fetch the preceding non-blank cell from column D;
If column D is NOT blank, return column D's value on the current row in another column:

```
 =IF(ISBLANK($D3),LOOKUP(2,1/($D$1:$D3<>""),$D$1:$D3),$D3)
```