# Copy row to next empty rows if any

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am new to excel and need some help here.
I have excel sheet where there is one to many mapping to each row. It means, in column A, I have one value and in column B, I have multiple(3-4) values mapped to column A value. Something like shown below.

[image]

I want to copy value from column A to next empty rows in column A till it find non-empty row. If there is no next empty row, like 2 in column A, it dont need to copy. 
Expected result as shown below.

[image]

Could you please help? 
This is just example. I have this situation for huge excel sheet.

All responses and comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill blank cells (Variation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382682/fill-blank-cells-variation) and [how to fill blank cells with the last preceding non-blank cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385038/in-excel-how-to-fill-blank-cells-with-the-last-preceding-non-blank-cell)

Comment: Thanks asongtourin. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert a new column between A & B and set B1=1 then copy this code to all the remaining rows it should work ie starting at row 2.

=IF(A2=0,B1,A2)

You might want to do a special copy/paste to set the values.