# how to fill blank cells in a dataframe with the last preceding non-blank cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this

```
A   
    abc
    dce
    fds
B   
    kjh
    abc
```

I want it to be like

```
A   
A   abc
A   dce
A   fds
B   
B   kjh
B   abc
```

A similar question was asked here, but for excel. [In Excel, how to fill blank cells with the last preceding non-blank cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385038/in-excel-how-to-fill-blank-cells-with-the-last-preceding-non-blank-cell)

Wondering if there's any simple and clean code can perform this operation in python.

edit: I actually have a large number of columns, sorry I didn't mention this to begin with. Therefore, df['col'] = df['col'].ffill() really answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for `ffill()`?

Comment: Yes, I think I am. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If no values are missing values use forward filling missing values by `ffill`:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].ffill()
```

If no values are empty strings first replace them to `NaN`s:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html).